# Run Command on Multiple Macs from Server

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to force shutdown multiple mac computers every night which are all connected to a server. I am unsure if the best way to do this is by running a sudo shutdown command through a for loop using IP addresses or ssh'ing. Or any other method. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any better method than ssh.

Generate and install your ssh key on those macs in the root account, in the file /var/root/.ssh/authorized_keys2 of each of them,

Ensure each of your mac has the line "PermitRootLogin yes" uncommented in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config, if not change it and relaunch sshd.

And finaly use ssh to run the shutdown command.

Here is the command line in bash shell :

```
for host in host01 host02 host03; do ssh root@$host "shutdown -h"; done
```